# Better software for business forecasting?

Tags: forecasting, software

I'd like to know what software provides better performance in business forecasting for thousands of SKU. Here the data is taken through databases.

I know three alternatives:

- Autobox
- SAS
- Forecast PRO

I'm looking for an option that can forecast every SKU automatically, given an error measure (preferably MAE).

I can't find a comparison for these sofware with the same data. What do you know about the performance of them?

Comment: Often one cannot find dataset to which many different software products are benchmarked against. I know only about this classic Airlines dataset:  http://calcnet.mth.cmich.edu/org/spss/V16_materials/DataSets_v16/airline_passengers.sav

Comment: According to each of the owners... they're all the best. ;)

Comment: at least forecast pro and autobox are open and compete in academic forecasting competition such as M competition. I have never seen SAS evaluated in a academic setting or evalauted by third party. Having said that it is always better to send a sample to all three vendors hold back some data, and compare it and do your own evaluation. You could do a rolling sample evaluation as these competition are usually single origin (which is flawed). You can look at this [article by Len Tashman](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207000000650)  on how to properly evaluate forecast.

Answer (score 0):

SPSS Modeler can be used, it has not so much outlier detection facilities as Autobox but in few cases I have seen that it can do decent job.